# Passive federated authentication with asp.net and acs in azure web role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, azure, acs

I want to deploy my azure web role application in the azure enviroment using window identity fondation framework but i have this error:

**The certificate with thumbprint 9f217128ecd4f952479274eb09f1f3fd2199538a was not found.**

This is part of my configuration file

```
 <federatedAuthentication>
      <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      <wsFederation  passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="https://webroboteu.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/wsfederation" realm="http://webrobot/"  requireHttps="false" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
      <serviceCertificate>
         <certificateReference  x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="my thumbprint" />
      </serviceCertificate>
  <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None"   />
```

```
    <add type="Microsoft.Samples.DPE.OAuth.Tokens.MachineKeySessionSecurityTokenHandler,  
        Microsoft.Samples.DPE.OAuth" />
    <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SessionSecurityTokenHandler, 
        Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"></remove>

                <add type="Microsoft.Samples.DPE.OAuth.Tokens.SimpleWebTokenHandler, Microsoft.Samples.DPE.OAuth" />
  </securityTokenHandlers>
  <issuerTokenResolver type="Microsoft.Samples.DPE.OAuth.ProtectedResource.ConfigurationBasedIssuerTokenResolver, Microsoft.Samples.DPE.OAuth">
    <serviceKeys>
      <add serviceName="http://webrobot/" serviceKey="my simmetric key" />
    </serviceKeys>
  </issuerTokenResolver>
```

When i remove the federatedAuthentication tag the problem is not present but is necessary in passive mode

Comment: Have you added the certificate to your certificate store?

Comment: I use a simmetric key and DPE.OAuth library with SWT token

Comment: i think that serviceCertificate tag is not necessary